# Change Default Html of Views

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How to change html so all newly added Views like Edit, Detail, list Views have that html instead of default html.

e.g. Instead default html (below one)

```
<h3>ListPage</h3>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PO_PoolName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PO_Code)
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want following html by default

```
<h3 class="page-header">ListPage</h3> 
<div class="section-container section-with-top-border">

    <!-- begin panel -->
    <div class="panel pagination-inverse m-b-0 clearfix">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <span class="pull-right ">
                    <a href="/Pools/Create" class="btn btn-lime  btn-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>
                        Create New
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table id="data-table" data-order='[[1,"asc"]]' class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="inverse">
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>model.PO_PoolName)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PO_Code)</th>
              </tr>
        </table>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please clarify what you want, your question is not clear.  Are you wanting css, or are you wanting to show certain partial views depending on certain criteria?  Where you say here is css by default - you show no css, just html

Comment: I want to change the template of view.

Comment: @user3079351, What do you mean template of view? you want to change layout of webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution

I modified and change the html of the t4 templates in the below directory

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView

which work fine for me.